# Train NER model in NLTK with custom corpus

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, named-entity-recognition

I have an annotated corpus in the conll2002 format, namely a tab separated file with a token, pos-tag, and IOB tag followed by entity tag. Example:

> John NNP B-PERSON

I want to train a **portuguese** NER model in NLTK, preferably the MaxEnt model. I do **not** want to use the "built-in" Stanford NER in NLTK since I was already able to use the stand-alone Stanford NER. I want to use the MaxEnt model to use as comparison to the Stanford NER.

I found [NLTK-trainer](http://nltk-trainer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/train_chunker.html) but I wasn't able to use it.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

Chapters 6 and 7 of the [nltk book](http://www.nltk.org/book/) explain how to train a "chunker" on an IOB-encoded corpus. The example in chapter 7 does NP chunking, but that's incidental-- your chunker will chunk whatever you train it on. You'll need to decide what features are useful for named entity recognition; chapter 6 covers the basics of choosing features for a classifier. Finally, look at the source for the features used by the nltk's own [named entity chunker](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/chunk/named_entity.html). They'll probably do a pretty good job in Portuguese too; then you can try adding stemming or other Portuguese-specific features.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to figure it out eventually, check my [github repository](https://github.com/arop/ner-re-pt/wiki/NLTK) for more info on this.

Comment: Glad to hear that. If my answer solved your problem, please "accept" it by clicking on the check mark.

Comment: PS. Took a look at your page. That's pretty abysmal performance you got so far...